# aws - browse to website - 404 not found - no such bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created a record set for my webiste volcalc.io and www.volcalc.io which is stored in an s3 bucket.

When I try to browse to the website I see this error:

```
404 Not Found

Code: NoSuchBucket
Message: The specified bucket does not exist
BucketName: volcalc.io
RequestId: xxx
HostId: xxx
```

The bucket name is www.volcalc.io, not volcalc.io

How do I change it to make it look for bucket named www.volcalc.io?

Answer (score 3):

See [Setting Up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html).

To allow requests for both example.com and www.example.com, you need to create two buckets even though you will host content in only one of them. You will need to configure the other bucket to redirect requests to the bucket that hosts the content.